# Split strings into multiple fields based on special characters and newline - Javascript

Tags: javascript, split, newline

I have a profile field where the data comes in the below format for each user profile.

User1 could have his profile field populated as below while user2 could have just one role/id/company listed in their profile.

```
RoleA : 123456 - company1 \n

RoleB : 234567 - company2 \n

RoleC : 891011
```

I am supposed to split the roles for each user into 1 field separated by commas and the id/company into another field separated by comma.

For the above data, the output should look like-

```
Role field - RoleA, RoleB, RoleC

ID/Company field - 123456-company1, 234567-company2.
```

This has to be done in `JavaScript`. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is something similar to below:

```js
function splitProfile(profile, roleList, idCompanyList) {
  var splitProfileString = profile.split(" : ");
  roleList.push(splitProfileString[0]);

  var splitIdCompanyString = splitProfileString[1].split(" - ");
  // check if there is a company for `id`
  if(splitIdCompanyString[1]) {
    idCompanyList.push(splitIdCompanyString[0] + "-" + splitIdCompanyString[1].replace(" \n", ""));
  }
}


var roleIdCompanyList = [
  "RoleA : 123456 - company1 \n",
  "RoleB : 234567 - company2 \n",
  "RoleC : 891011"
];

var roleList = [];
var idCompanyList = [];

roleIdCompanyList.forEach(function(roleIdCompany) {
  splitProfile(roleIdCompany, roleList, idCompanyList);
});

console.log(roleList.join(", ")); // RoleA, RoleB, RoleC
console.log(idCompanyList.join(", ")); // 123456-company1, 234567-company2
```

I tried to think that the input and the output are exactly similar to the ones you provided in the question. In any case, I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!